# Exactly what folders/files need to be deleted when uninstalling Meteor?

Tags: meteor

Uninstalling a corrupt version of Meteor (1.2) - Windows 10.  I'm aware that .../local/.meteor and .../local/PaxHeader must be deleted.  Are there any other folders/files that need to be removed?  How about any Registry entries?